# coding principle behind "if everything has it then nothing should have it"

Tags: function, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

As I am looking through the source code of a project I'm working on, I see the following pattern:

```
//in one class:
function getNavigation($region_id, $clear_cache = FALSE){ .. }

//in another class 
getPage($region_id, $clear_cache = FALSE){ .. }

//etc..
```

..and so on.  These functions all have the same second parameter, with a default value of `false`.

Furthermore, looking through the calls to these methods, each call ONLY passes one parameter, the `$region_id` - never a value for `$clear_cache`.  I say ONLY, but there is one exception in test coding, that's it, where it's set to TRUE.

My intention is to remove the clear_cache variable and replace it with another needed parameter on the premise that "if everything has it then nothing should have it, and we should just assume it's the default way." I usually don't ask non-specific coding questions, but is there any *name* to this principle in coding?

If the coder wants to do that one test case then they can just manually change the value :)

Comment: Public methods/functions essentially represent an API. In languages where you are allowed to define the default state for a argument this is used heavily to simplify object usage while still offering full flexibility. If you remove the `clear_cache` argument, a programmer who needs to call your method/function with a different default state would need to extend your whole class/structure just to override your function so that he can change it (and many times they'd have to write the whole implementation boilerplate). Hence, why not leave it as an option? It provides flexibility at no cost.

Comment: _"My intention is to remove the clear_cache variable and replace it with another needed parameter"_ - don't get what you'd actually want to achieve with that, or how specifically ... In this specific instance, it would probably make most sense to check for debug mode based on a constant, and not a variable that needs to be passed into every single function/method call.

Comment: In your particular case it looks like a good idea to get rid of this parameter, because it seems to me that it is none of these functions' business to clear the cache.  If you need to clear the cache, you could easily invoke some new `clearCache()` function.  So, go ahead and do it.  Other than that, I do not know of any pattern that stands for what you have in your mind.

Comment: @zwer in this case I will probably not remove it, but move it to the 3rd optional parameter (vectored to FALSE).  But these functions would not be called as an API, but you never know :)

Comment: Your particular case has nothing to do with good design but is an example of someone not trying harder to write better unit tests. Unit tests should not drive the application design. They should rely on techniques such as mocking, white box access etc in order to achieve full test coverage without changing the existing code.